# php curl scrape not working

Tags: php, curl

My scraping code is not working , I used php cURL , But not returning page content . So please help me , how can I get all content .

```
function getSslPage($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

$url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple";
$ch = getSslPage($url);

echo $ch;
```

Comment: You haven't posted any errors that you're getting. Please include all relevant information and please format the question so that all code is nicely formatted together (thank you).

Comment: $url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple";
$ch = getSslPage($url);

echo $ch;

Its returning blank , not getting any error, but not getting target site content

Comment: I take it you didn't understand my suggestion about formatting your question because you copy/pasted some code in the comment box. Due to that, I will excuse myself from helping you and I wish you good luck solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much .

I'm just asking ..........

Its returning blank , not getting any error, but not getting target site content

Comment: Ensure you have curl extension installed and consult your web server logs to see what the error reported is.

Comment: It's not showing any error . Also I run in my local server . Also You can  test that code your side . Hope you can see bank page .

I checked my log , there only scrap up-to

<script src="/Scripts/BrowserHacks/IE/IEOutdated.js?h=F3A6E27FCF950E9A1542D5869DF15970" type="text/javascript"></script>
this html then scrap was broken

Comment: *Please, post additional code and content **inside** the question through editing it, rather than posting it into comments*

Comment: Your code works for me. I can't find any problem. I've changed `echo $ch;` to `var_dump($ch);` and get a result starting with `string(89173) "<!DOCTYPE html>...` rest of the html document follows and is closed with `</html>"`.

Comment: Ya. Right ....... But you did not checked , this html not a whole html ... I need all html from target link "https://www.woolworths.com.au/Shop/SearchProducts?search=Fresh%20Apple"

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after your `curl_exec()` call and copy/paste here the output:

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}
```